# iMacros Scripting Edition - How to switch browser to record in Firefox?

Tags: imacros

I'm running iMacros scripting edition in WindowsXP and also have the free add-on for firefox. I would like to switch recording browser from IE to Firefox in the iMacros scripting edition. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can download iMacros Browser and use that to record. But iMacros Scripting also means use of JavaScript in iMacros.

To use JS means to take code of iMacros and put it .js file for use.

Comment: IceD I mean changing the use of browser (IE) that iMacros browser uses to record to FF instead of IE. Some pages when recording in the iMacros browser ask to update your browser to IE9 in which I'm running XP so IE8 is the highest.

Comment: Use the FireFox it's much simpler, faster and effective. iMacros browser (licensed) gives you option to use image recognition. Anything other then that is supported in FireFox.